# Cannot install Guest Additions on Kali 2.0

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kernel-module

I am installing the new Kali (2.0) and I am unable to install the guest additions successfully.

I explain you all the steps I have done:

First of all I made sure I have the correct repositories (I think these are the correct ones):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

I have updated and upgraded.

Then I have installed the linux-headers (maybe the mistake is here, but I don't think so)

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
apt-get install dkms linux-source linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Then I mounted the CD, give it 755 permissions and executed it. This is what I get:

```
Building the main Guest Additions module ...done.
Building the shared folder support module ...fail!
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
Installing the Window System drivers
Warning: unknown version of the X Window System installed.  Not installing
X Window System drivers.
 ...done.
Installing graphics libraries and desktop services components ...done.
```

I have installed the following:

```
apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

But I still get the same result.

For further information, this is my kernel:

```
root@kali:~# uname -r
4.0.0-kali1-686-pae
```

It seems I have the module installed but it doesn't work:

```
root@kali:~# lsmod | grep vbox
vboxguest             180224  5
```

My virtualbox version is 4.3.20
Any idea¿? Thank you very much.

/var/log/vboxadd-install.log

```
In file included from /tmp/vbox.0/dirops.c:19:0:
/tmp/vbox.0/dirops.c: In function ‘sf_getdent’:
/tmp/vbox.0/dirops.c:129:29: error: ‘struct file’ has no member named ‘f_dentry’
     sf_g = GET_GLOB_INFO(dir->f_dentry->d_inode->i_sb);
                             ^
/tmp/vbox.0/vfsmod.h:144:60: note: in definition of macro ‘GET_GLOB_INFO’
 # define GET_GLOB_INFO(sb)       ((struct sf_glob_info *) (sb)->s_fs_info)
                                                            ^
/tmp/vbox.0/dirops.c:135:16: error: ‘struct file’ has no member named ‘f_dentry’
     inode = dir->f_dentry->d_inode;
                ^
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.0-kali1-common/scripts/Makefile.build:263: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/dirops.o' failed
make[4]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/dirops.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.0-kali1-common/Makefile:1407: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/vbox.0' failed
make[3]: *** [_module_/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
Makefile:145: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.footer:79: recipe for target 'vboxsf' failed
make: *** [vboxsf] Error 2
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

Comment: `Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong`?

Comment: yeah sorry, I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entering "no member named ‘f_dentry’" into a search engine indicates this to be a [known issue](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=65299) of kernel 3.19 introducing breaking changes to `struct file`, which makes the (older) VirtualBox 4.3.20 code fail to compile.

Biting my tongue firmly with regards to [Linux kernel maintainers' policy on such breaking changes](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/stable_api_nonsense.txt), I am afraid you will just have to figure out whether downgrading the kernel or upgrading your VirtualBox is the "correct" fix for your problem.

Comment: I very much prefer Linux over currently available alternatives, but this particular problem has been driving me up the walls more than once myself, both as a user and as a software architect.

Comment: What virtualbox version do you recommend to me ?? thank u

Comment: @aDoN: I do not use VirtualBox myself, and I don't know your requirements. Perhaps you're better off asking such questions in the VirtualBox forums (my first link), they're not exactly on-topic here on SO.